# How are variables with the same name typically resolved?

Tags: gcc, compiler-construction, scope, runtime

Suppose this is the call stack of my program at a particular point:

```
|    b = 2       |
|    c = 3       | <- function f2
| return address |
| function args  |
|     ...        |
|    c = 10      | <- function f1
|     ...        |
```

`f1()` calls `f2()`.

**When variable `c` is referenced, how is it resolved?** Is the stack searched linearly top down to find the first variable named `c` in scope, or is there some other mechanism that takes care of this more efficiently?

If the stack is searched every time, wont it be an overhead when a non existent variable `d` is referenced, because the stack will be searched all the way to find out that there is no such variable in scope?

Comment: The stack isn't "searched", the compiler knows how many variables are there so the function ends up knowing that 5th local variable is i.e. 48 bytes away from the stack pointer.

Comment: "Overthinking it" comes to mind. Don't confuse a *language* with an *implementation*. The language specifies precisely how your code behaves, and it will do so.

Comment: When your code is compiled, any use of a variable name is replaced with an address relative to the current stack frame pointer. No searching necessary.

Comment: +1 @KerrekSB No need to think about the stack, the scoping rules  dictate (1) it's known at compiletime which variable is used and (2) undefined variables are a compile-time error. This also applies to every answer/comment talking in terms of the stack!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In C++, during runtime the variables don't have names. Variable names are only there for the convenience of the programmer. Variables have scope in the code, they don't have a scope in the stack.

So the stack is not searched during runtime. During compilation the variable name is converted into a memory address.

Comment: If memory is only allocated at runtime, how come the memory address is available at compiletime?

Comment: I don't see the connection between my answer and your follow-up question, though interesting by itself.

Answer (score 1):

The (C or C++) compiler has the difficult task of organizing each call frame.

It is translating, when emitting machine code related to a local variable in your source code, the access and modifications of local variables into suitable instructions (often using the stack or frame pointer as some base).

A given location in a call frame can be (and usually is, when the compiler is optimizing) used for several purposes.

Some local variables have no counter parts in the call frame: they only exist in registers. Others are sometimes spilled. A good [register allocator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Register_allocation) tries hard to avoid spilling.

Call frame layout, register allocations, instructions scheduling are difficult tasks of an optimizing compiler.

If you are curious and know a little bit about your x86 processor instruction set, you might try to code a tiny C++ file `tiny.cc` and compile it with `g++ -Wall -fverbose-asm -O -S tiny.cc`  then look into the generated `tiny.s` with e.g. an editor like `gedit` or `emacs` or a pager like `less`.

Answer (score 1):

References are resolved by scope, based on where the variable is DEFINED, not where it's ASSIGNED.  Since in your example you don't show any DEFINITIONS it's impossible to say.

In C-based languages there are no nested procedures (ignoring the issue of "thunks" in some of them), so the stack, per se, is not searched.  However, you can have, within a single procedure, static scope nesting with the `{}` characters, and then the innermost scope (relative to the point of reference) "wins".  Otherwise, it's procedure scope, class scope, and then static/global scope.